# Make [osx-10.9] a synonym of [osx-mavericks]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The tags [osx-mavericks](/questions/tagged/osx-mavericks) and [osx-10.9](/questions/tagged/osx-10.9) both refer to the same thing. They should be synoynms with [osx-mavericks](/questions/tagged/osx-mavericks) as the master tag the same as the other osx tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OK.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/osx-mavericks/synonyms)